# Detect checkbox click/change event in Chrome 93 for desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, checkbox

This code:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="switchService">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="switchService">Service</label>
</div>

$("#switchService").on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

works in Firefox and in Chrome for Android.
But in Firefox 93 for Desktop (Windows 7) does not trigger the event.

I also tried a lot of different syntaxes like:

```
$("#switchService").on('click', function() {
$("#switchService").on('change', function() {
$("#switchService").change(function() {
```

All of the above works in all browsers I tried but the Chrome 93 for desktop.

Is there a specific syntax for it?
Of course javascript is enabled, as other scripts work fine.

Comment: This seems ***incredibly*** unlikely to be a bug specifically on Chrome v93 in Windows 7. Are you sure it's not something in your code, for example a race condition between the element being created and the event handler being bound?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What is a "race-condition"? I'm not using all these syntaxes at the same time! It was just an example of which trials I did. But once per time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the "race-condition"-type difficulties mentioned by @RoryMcCrossan if you use event delegation like shown here:

```
$("body").on("click","#switchService",  function() { ... })
         .on("change","#switchService", function() { ... })
         .on("change","#switchService", function() { ... });
```

Comment: What is a "race-condition"? I'm not using *all* these syntaxes at the same time! It was just an example of which trials I did. But once per time!

Comment: Rory was referring to a situation where two things are happening at the same time in a browser: the building-up of the DOM and the script that refers to certain elements within the DOM. Depending which of these activities finishes first, the script will either succeed or fail. That is why we call it a "race" condition: they are "racing" each other. By using a "delegated" event handling we actually bind the event to the body element but will execute it only when a certain child element within this body (which does not need to exist at binding time)  is triggering the specified event.